# how to control dialog background touches?

Tags: java, android, dialog, onclick

I have android dialogs in my app.

in one of the I want the background to be touchable but clicking around the dialog won't close it.

in the second dialog I want any click on the background close the dialog.

what attributes should i use to control this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);`

didn't worked for me

but this did:

`mToolTipDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the dialog from being closed when the background or the area outside of the dialog is clicked, do this:

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Set it to **true** to do the opposite.

Note: `this` refers to a Context.

Comment: I want the dialog not to block buttons in the background. will this do it? buttons at the background are still clickable?

Comment: what to do for API 8?

Comment: No, the dialog will be modal i.e. you cannot touch buttons in the background - that's how dialog work. The `setFinishOnTouchOutside` method works for API 11 or later. For earlier API level, you cannot touch outside the dialog, so you don't need to worry. Have you tried your dialog via an emulator using API 10 and earlier?